# Visual studio 2010 missing template files (but not in the progam itself)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I'm looking to create a copy of the default class template for VS2010, everywhere I've looked says that the class template should be in:

```
C:\<Program Files>\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Code\1033
```

But it's not in there, the only two files in there are:

```
AdoNetEntityDataModelT4CodeGenCSharp.zip
AdoNetEntityDataModelT4SelfTrackingCodeGenCSharp.zip
```

The class templates and others work fine though in VS itself, and none are missing, where could they be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on a 64 bit system I'd imagine they would be in `Program Files (x86)`

I found my VS2012 templates in here:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Code\1033
```

Regarding the content, I had two files in there, one .cs and one template file:

**Class.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
$if$ ($targetframeworkversion$ >= 3.5)using System.Linq;
$endif$using System.Text;
$if$ ($targetframeworkversion$ >= 4.5)using System.Threading.Tasks;
$endif$
namespace $rootnamespace$
{
    class $safeitemrootname$
    {
    }
}
```

**Class.vstemplate**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<VSTemplate Version="3.0.0" Type="Item" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate/2005">
  <TemplateData>
    <Name Package="{FAE04EC1-301F-11d3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}" ID="2245" />
    <Description Package="{FAE04EC1-301F-11d3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}" ID="2262" />
    <Icon Package="{FAE04EC1-301F-11d3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}" ID="4515" />
    <TemplateID>Microsoft.CSharp.Class</TemplateID>
    <ProjectType>CSharp</ProjectType>
    <SortOrder>90</SortOrder>
    <RequiredFrameworkVersion>2.0</RequiredFrameworkVersion>
    <NumberOfParentCategoriesToRollUp>1</NumberOfParentCategoriesToRollUp>
    <DefaultName>Class.cs</DefaultName>
  </TemplateData>
  <TemplateContent>
        <References>
            <Reference>
                <Assembly>System</Assembly>
            </Reference>
        </References>

    <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true">Class.cs</ProjectItem>
  </TemplateContent>
</VSTemplate>
```